# Is there any way to catch exceptions thrown by exe files in powershell scripts?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell, exe, jit

I'm writing a powershell script which mimics the behavior of watch.
It works fine until I watch an exe which throws an exception.

When that happens the JIT debugger from Visual Studio kicks in and opens a dialog box.
I have tried catching the exception using a try/catch block as in the code sample bellow.

I know I can turn of the debugger in VS, but I don't want to turn it since it's useful for debugging. I just want to catch/suppress the exception and the popup when it's encountered in this script.

I have read some sources that claim it's not doable in powershell, but I'm hoping that they are mistaken and that there is some clever way around the issue. Does anyone have any tips?

What I've tried:

```
$tick = "-"

while ($true)
{
    try {
        $out = invoke-expression "$args"
    }
    catch {
        $out = "Error: " + $_.Exception.Message
    } finally {
        cls
        $out
        $tick
        if ($tick -eq "-") {$tick = "+"} else {$tick = "-"}
        sleep 1 
    }
}
```

I've also tried adding `[Exception]` and `[System.IO.IOException]`(The concrete exception I recieved) to the catch block, without any more luck.

Answer (score 0):

Exe's use exitcodes to return error status instead of .NET exceptions. A workaround is to check the $lasterrorexitcode. If you want to make use of try/catch blocks you can issue a throw statement if the lasterrorcode is not equal to zero. Note: One thing to be cautious of--some exe's use non-zero error codes to return a status other than error.

Here's an example:

### Wrap in try/catch block

```
try {
    $result = some-exe.exe

    if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) {
        
        $result = $result -join "`n"
        throw "$result `n"
    }
}
catch {
  write-error "$_"
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't catch the exception from the exe, and doesn't stop the JIT debugger from kicking in. The catch block catches the exception that gets thrown with the ```throw``` keyword, but not the exception from the exe. The exception from the exe still gets printed to the console, and the JIT debugger still opens a popup. As you can see my original script wraps the statement in a try/catch block, so there is no extra catching of exe exceptions in this script.

Comment: As stated exe's don't throw exceptions they set error codes. You can kind of fake it by checking errorcodes and redirecting any output a variable or temp file and using output in throw statement. Here's example of using a tempfile and redirecting all screen output http://poshcode.org/3756

Comment: I am downvoting this because the asker is completely right.  I have a .NET application throwing an exception and popping up a JIT debugger window.  I cannot escape it unless I click on the button.  This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I agree with @MattSlagle I have an executable that, for test proposes, I throw an exception in the beginning of the code and when my powershell script runs a popup windows appears due to the exception and I have to click on the button to continue. The point here is that the exception is not caught on the try catch block of my powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

(Possibly) clever ways around the issue (first two involve sending keystroke to thrown exception dialog box to dismiss it automatically)

1. Use WASP powershell module (on Codeplex) to query for existence of error dialog for a few seconds after you execute the EXE, and if dialog window exists then send key to dismiss it
2. Use system.diagnostics.process to start EXE, and register some combination of the 3 possible events: Disposed, ErrorDataReceived, and Exited, to distinguish between EXE throwing an exception or not.
3. If you can load the EXE as an assembly, and then execute its Main method, then you can could catch an exception via try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

If a process hangs then there will be no exit code since it newer exited on its own.

I would try monitoring the process instead to see if it's still alive as suggested by @Χpẘ or other means.